# Getting 403 error for while access OneDrive for Business APIs using SAML Auth

Tags: saml, onedrive

We are working on OneDrive for Business ReST API and using SAML for authentication. The SAML token is getting generated successfully but when we try to access the any of the API, we are getting HTTP 403 error.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "accessDenied",
    "message": "The caller does not have permission to perform the action."
     }
}
```

This was working properly till last week of July. Please suggest if there is any change due to which this is broken or any way we can get is back to working.